# SPF, Sender ID and DKIM signing - Does Sender ID need to be configured if DKIM signing in place?

Tags: spf, dkim, email

While learning about SPF, Sender ID and DKIM siging, it seems that Sender ID and DKIM exist to solve similar problems. In addition, Sender ID is discussed in a fairly unflattering light on several of the sites I've read such as [openspf.org](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_vs_Sender_ID).

Is there any benefit in using Sender ID if DKIM is in place? It seems like an overhead that could also prone to error if I need to maintain both SPF and Sender ID TXT records.

Comment: I don't even think Microsoft is using Sender ID anymore, and they "invented" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to compare SPF to Sender ID, not DKIM to Sender ID. SPF/Sender IDs purpose is to to check whether sender is authorized to send a message on behalf of a domain from a certain IP space. DKIMs purpose is to validate message content integrity and relationship with a claimed senders domain.

The benefit of using Sender ID in addition to SPF is questionable due to low adoption rate and limited client software implementation availability for Sender-ID.

You also might be interested to read about [DMARC](http://www.dmarc.org/) (Domain-based Message Authentication, Reporting & Conformance) framework which operates on top of SPF and DKIM and is adopted by Google, Facebook and other organizations for email authentication.